# Communicate between Recyclerviews in Fragments (ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i have 3 Fragments which i access with Horizontal Swiping (ViewPager). In each Fragment is a recyclerview (source, translation and description). Now i have implemented code to enable selecting items in the recyclerview. What i would love now is,that when i click on an item in the first recylcerview, an item in the second and third recylcerview also get selected. 
Do I need to go over the activity that starts the fragments, or what would be the recommended method to do this. I dont need code, just the best possible way to do this...

thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways of achieving this, but in general, you're looking for a publish/subscriber/observer solution.

One way to achieve this is my leveraging the hosting Activity to [communicate among fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). In this approach, you define an interface and have your Fragments each implement that interface, then when one of the RecyclerViews' items is selected, you notify the other Fragments. Another solution is to use an EventBus like [GreenRobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).

I personally like the EventBus approach because it is clear, simple, and requires less code.

Comment: Thanks very much..I have implemented an interface, so that when i click in a fragment, that position of the clicked item is sent to the activity. Now my problem is, how to let the other fragments with the other recyclerviews select also the item. The item selection is implemented in the onBindViewholder of the Adapters, but how can i access this from the activtiy?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an activity and callbacks to communicate with rest of the fragments -> doing it this way you can keep everything in one place, and the code is easier to maintain in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have FragmentA, FragmentB,FragmentC.
You need to create listener like this:

```
public interface OnRecyclerviewListener{
    public void onItemClick(View v); //or something like for need in another fragments
}
```

In your Activity you need to set this listener for communication with other fragments

```
public class BaseActivity extand Activity{
private OnRecyclerviewListener onRecyclerviewListener=null;

public OnRecyclerviewListener getRecyclerviewListener(){
return onRecyclerviewListener;
}

public void setRecyclerviewListener(OnRecyclerviewListener listener){
this.onRecyclerviewListener=listener;
}
```

Fragmetn B and C must implement this Listener and set to BaseActivity in onCreate(...)

```
((BaseActivity)getActivity()).setRecyclerviewListener(this);
```

in Fragment A y can call

```
    if(((BaseActivity)getActivity).getRecyclerviewListener()!=null){
    ((BaseActivity)getActivity).getRecyclerviewListener().onItemClick(view);//or something what you set in interface method;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much..I have implemented an interface, so that when i click in a fragment, that position of the clicked item is sent to the activity. Now my problem is, how to let the other fragments with the other recyclerviews select also the item. The item selection is implemented in the onBindViewholder of the Adapters, but how can i access this from the activtiy?